# Linq to query matching column from a table and populate in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table as below:

| Id | First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Murray |
| 2 | Smith | Murray |
| 3 | Natasha | Murray |
| 4 | Steve | Kay |
| 5 | Bill | Kay |

Now, If I query for a name example *John*, it should produce the results with the matching records with same lastname and put into another table as below:

| Id | Name | Matching name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith |
| 2 | John | Natasha |

How can i achieve this using Linq?

Comment: Is it SQL Server Table?

Comment: yes it is.. i want it to be queried in linq to use it in my class

Comment: Seems like simple self join. What did you try?

Comment: i wrote a sql query for that... but i want to convert this to linq..                                  
  select * from table d inner join ( select lastName from table where lastName  = 'Murray'  group by lastName having count ( distinct firstName) > 1)  dup on dup.lastName  = d.lastName ;

Answer (score 0):

Lets define the class for data

```
class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

this is something that should be part of your question. Now fill in the data

```
Table[] table = new Table[]
{
    new Table{ Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Murray" },
    new Table{ Id = 2, FirstName = "Smith", LastName = "Murray" },
    new Table{ Id = 3, FirstName = "Natasha", LastName = "Murray" },
    new Table{ Id = 4, FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Kay" },
    new Table{ Id = 5, FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Kay" }
};
```

and that is also something that should be part of your question. If you omit that you greatly reduce chance of getting an aswer. Now just join the table with itself on the last name.

```
var query = from t1 in table
            from t2 in table
            where t1.LastName == t2.LastName && t1.Id != t2.Id
            select new { t2.Id, Name = t1.FirstName, MatchingName = t2.FirstName };

foreach (var row in query.Where(t => t.Name == "John"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

and voilà

```
 { Id = 2, Name = John, MatchingName = Smith }
 { Id = 3, Name = John, MatchingName = Natasha }
```

The only thing that is different is the Id, from the data provided I have no idea how John or Natasha could be related to Id number 2.